# How to specify which form to submit?

Tags: html, forms

I have a button that is inside of a HTML form, but I want button to submit another form on the page. Both forms have unique IDs. How do I identify which form the button should submit?

Answer (score 1):

1. HTML Setup: Two forms with unique IDs, and a button in the first form.

```html
    <!-- First form with the button -->
    <form id="form1">
        <!-- Form contents -->
        <button type="button" id="submitOtherForm">Submit Other Form</button>
    </form>
    
    <!-- Second form which you want to submit -->
    <form id="form2">
        <!-- Form contents -->
    </form>
```

2. JavaScript: Add an event listener to the button to submit the second form.

```js
<script>
    document.getElementById('submitOtherForm').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('form2').submit();
    });
</script>
```

In this example, the button with the ID `submitOtherForm` is inside `form1`. When clicked, it triggers JavaScript to submit `form2`. Note that the type of the button is set to `button` to prevent it from submitting `form1` (the default behavior if the type were `submit`).

Answer (score 0):

Reading [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) documentation was helpful:

> The `<form>` element to associate the button with (its form owner). The value of this attribute must be the `id` of a `<form>` in the same document. (If this attribute is not set, the `<button>` is associated with its ancestor `<form>` element, if any.)
>
> This attribute lets you associate `<button>` elements to `<form>`s anywhere in the document, not just inside a `<form>`. It can also override an ancestor `<form>` element.

TLDR use `form` attribute to reference the target form by its ID, e.g.

```
<form id="foo">
</form>

<form id="bar">
  <button type="submit">Submit Bar</button>
  <button type="submit" form="foo">Submit Foo</button>
</form>
```

In this example, clicking "Submit Foo" will submit `#foo` form.